# CSS: How can I right-justify text against centered text?

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<div class="css_class_1">
    <div class="css_class_2">
        A 1 A 1 A 1
    </div>
    <div class="css_class_3">
        B 2 B 2
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make the text `A 1 A 1 A 1` horizontally-centered. And I would like to make the text `B 2 B 2` right-justified so that it's right border is aligned with the right border of `A 1 A 1 A 1`.

How can I do it? Please show the css I should define for each of the three mentioned classes.

Comment: There is a big difference between "right aligned" and "right justified" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your right justify text inside the center one:

```css
.css_class_1 {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

.css_class_2 {
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.css_class_3 {
  background: red;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_class_1">
    <div class="css_class_2">
        A 1 A 1 A 1
      
      <div class="css_class_3">
          B 2 B 2
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```css
.css_class_2{
  text-align: right;
}

.css_class_3{
  text-align: right;
}
.css_class_1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="css_class_1">
        <div class="css_class_2">
            A 1 A 1 A 1
        </div>
        <div class="css_class_3">
            B 2 B 2
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.css_class_2 {
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.css_class_3 {
  text-align: right;
  border-right: 2px solid dodgerblue;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.css_class_1 {
  text-align:center;
}
.parent {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_class_1">
  <div class="parent">
  <div class="css_class_2">
    A 1 A 1 A 1
  </div>
  <div class="css_class_3">
    B 2 B 2
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to give the following css

```css
.css_class_1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
body {   /* or grand parent element */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_class_1">
  <div class="css_class_2">
    A 1 A 1 A 1
  </div>
  <div class="css_class_3">
    B 2 B 2
  </div>
</div>
```

**Or**

If you are fine with CSS3's `width: max-content`, you can make it smaller.

```css
.css_class_1 {
  text-align: right;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="css_class_1">
  <div class="css_class_2">
    A 1 A 1 A 1
  </div>
  <div class="css_class_3">
    B 2 B 2
  </div>
</div>
```