# Align text center and level on the left of the text HTML

Tags: html, css

I've made a bullet point list in HTML. I then centered the text and the bullet points. However once I center the text I want the text to be in a straight line on the left so my bullet points aren't staggered. Is there any way I can do this.

[image]

My CSS is as fallows
Centering my text

```
  .l-section.wpb_row.height_auto.color_alternate {
      text-align:center;
    }
```

Centering my bullet points

```
.wpb_text_column p:last-child, .wpb_text_column ul:last-child, .wpb_text_column ol:last-child{
   list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: Add text-align:center to parent and for the bulletins add text-align:left

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372065, but I've reopened it as I don't think they're the same questions. Linking this here in the comments in case I'm wrong!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly the only difference I see is the referred post has text align right and this has left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your `ul` to display as an `inline-block` to allow that to be affected by the outer element's `text-align` property, then give it its own `text-align` set to `left` to align the inner list items:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Foobar</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: left;` to the bulletin list displayed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    li {
       text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h4>An Unordered List:</h4>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox over your ul elements and his father:

```
        .father {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-content: flex-start;
        }
        ul{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-content: flex-start;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using css flexbox property.
Below is my code

**HTML CODE**

```
<h4>Heading</h4>
<div class="container">
 <ul>
  <li>1st row</li>
  <li>2nd row</li>
  <li>3rd row</li>
  <li>4th row</li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.container{display:flex; align-items:center;justify-content:center}
h4{text-align:center;}
```